# Android timer to auto run method

Tags: android

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
//                  runs a method every 2000ms
//       example    runThisEvery2seconds();
         } 
    }, 2000);         

} //end of OnCreate

public void runThisEvery2seconds()
{
    //code that runs every 2 seconds
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Run from timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

For the time being I have tried this but the Toast message doesn't appear. Don't know if you're allowed to do that but anyway in general, if I actually execute code inside runThisEvery2seconds() , other than Toast, will it run every 2 seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you call `show()` when you make your toast message.

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Run from timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And no, your message won't be displayed every 2 seconds.  `postDelayed` runs the task once, after the specified delay, but after that it's done.  If you want to have tasks run on a schedule, take a look at Java's [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing the `Toast`.
Call the `show` method.

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Run from timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.show()` end of the toast.

> Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Run from timer",
>   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

Call the `show()` method.

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Run from timer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```